# What expansions can I use with the new Core set without conversion?

Tags: pathfinder-adventure

Paizo released an new edition of the [Core Set](https://paizo.com/products/btq01ws7?Pathfinder-Adventure-Card-Game-Core-Set). There are meaningful rules changes, which require a conversion guide to play with older games. Unfortunately, I'm new to the game and I can't tell which products would require conversion and which work out of the box.

How do I tell which products require conversion to be played, and which can be played out of the box with no conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dragon's Demand is the new Adventure Card Game Core set. [Curse of the Crimson Throne](https://paizo.com/products/btq01ws8) is only released adventure path designed to work out of the box with the Dragon's Demand Core set.

The previous adventure card game sets require conversion:

- Rise of the Runelords
- Skull & Shackles
- Wrath of the Righteous
- Mummy's Mask
- The Ultimate Decks and the various Class decks.

There is a [conversion guide for specific cards](https://paizo.com/pacg/conversion) for using products that require conversion with the Dragon's Demand Core Set rules or cards. There are far too many to include here, but they fall into different headings:
Rules, Character Roles, Locations, Cohorts, Scourges, Ships, Story Banes, Monsters, Weapons, Spells, Armors, Items, Allies, and Blessings.

The primary transition guide covers most of the changes, and has been [publicly posted on Paizo's site](https://paizo.com/community/blog/v5748dyo6sgpd). I have a copy of the photo here:
[image: transition guide photo]

Since you said you were new to the game, check out the [frequently asked questions about the game](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1he). There are currently 77 questions in the list.

The Ultimate Decks and the various Class decks were designed mostly for the organized play (Pathfinder Adventure Card Game Society). So if you use them at all, you will need to use the conversion guide also.

The game will have no more expansions after [Curse of the Crimson Throne](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Pathfinder_Adventure_Card_Game). As there are no more releases, they [discontinued the Organized Play](https://paizo.com/community/blog/v5748dyo6shlm) also.

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks. Is there any kind of branding or text on the game itself that indicates whether it's compatible with the older or newer base game?

Comment: Curse of the Crimson Throne is the only release designed to work with the new Core set. I updated to clarify the game has ceased releasing new sets.